# Как обновить данные SharedPreferense в приложении Android

Tags: android

Как обновить файлы настроек в android приложении? 
У меня в приложении я сохраняю файл настроек в shared_prefs/appPrefs.xml.
Далее при необходимости выгружаю на удаленный сервер. Далее при необходимости загружаю в память смартфона эти настройки. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: я скачиваю эти файлы, но приложение не подтягивает эти настройки, хотя они скачиваются и меняются. В DeviceFileExplorer я вижу, что файл с настройками обновился, но приложение его не видит. Только после полного перезапуска приложения настройки подтягиваются. 
В качестве класса для работы с SharedPrefernce я использую Singleton.В качестве параметра добавил булевый флаг update, который показывает, что необходимо создать обьект заново. Но почему приложение не подхватывает настройки.

```
public class AppPreferenceSingleton {

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private static AppPreferenceSingleton mAppPreferenceSingleton = null;
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private static SharedPreferences mAppPref = null;
private static SharedPreferences.Editor mEditorAppPref = null;

public static AppPreferenceSingleton getInstance(Context context, boolean update) {
    if (update){
        mContext = context;
        mAppPreferenceSingleton = new AppPreferenceSingleton();
    } else if (mAppPreferenceSingleton == null) {
        mContext = context;
        mAppPreferenceSingleton = new AppPreferenceSingleton();
    }
    return mAppPreferenceSingleton;
}

@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
private AppPreferenceSingleton() {
    mAppPref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.APP_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditorAppPref = mAppPref.edit();

public int getProgress( int questName) {
  return mAppPref.getInt(questName, 0);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте под дебагером или логами посмотреть изменяется ли экземпляр `SharedPreferences` после пересоздания синглтона (сравнить `hashCode()` до и после). Я раньше подозревал, но так и не удосужился проверить, что контекст хранит их экземпляры и по тому же имени выдаёт повторно. А сам `SharedPreferences` читает файл только при создании экземпляра и дальше оперирует данными в оперативной памяти не перечитывая файл (как бы незачем, если экземпляр один и изменения должны производиться через его `Editor`).

Comment: Да вы правы, даже после создания нового экземпляра в контексте сохраняется старая ссылка. Теперь вопрос, как удалить или обновить старую ссылку не убивая контекст?

Comment: А не проще забить на преференсы и сохраняться просто в файл? Я не думаю что мы можем как-то повлиять на создание экземпляров внутри контекста. Или парсить файл, полученный с сервера и через `Editor` заносить новые значения. **P.S.** А вообще-то у вас торчит незакрытый `Editor` (бессмысленная строка `mAppPref.edit();`) - попробуйте устранить все подобные нюансы и провериться ещё раз.

Comment: Забить то можно, но проблему охота решить как то. Ну например, я вдруг захочу как то восстановить настройки приложени. Пользователь скачивает файл в виде sharedPreference, а дальше то что? Вручную перезапускать приложение, а почему в ручную, потому что я проверил, что файлы sharedPreference не обновляются в контексте даже при перезапуске активити методом finish. Обновление происходит, когда полностью выгружаешь приложение из памяти.

Comment: А насчет вот этого (((бессмысленная строка mAppPref.edit();)), это да, ошибка при копировании)).

Comment: Могу предложить такой костылик: при обновлении сгенерить рандомное имя преференса, записать под этим именем файл, загрузить его, взять все данные и занести в основной через `Editor`. Временный файл после перенесения удалить.

Comment: Да это единственный вариант, и он рабочий, я проверил))). И работает в принципе быстро)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный возможный вариант, пробовал все, ничего не помогло. Единственный вариант, через костыль. 
1. Скачать файлы из удаленного хранилища, назвать их по-другому например добавить к файлу _temp
2. Cоздать временные объекты SharedPreference.
3. Считать все данные из скачанных префов в HashMap.
4. Из HashMap копировать все в рабочий преференс обычным способом через Editor.